# How to disable or uncheck the toggle switch when clicking on the icon in multiple icons

Tags: angular, typescript, click, toggle

In my angular application I have some icons and on right side I have one toggle switch by default the switch is in ON stage
and when we click on any of the icon the color will change from white to red among multiple icons the switch should be turned to OFF stage and vice versa (means when we click on icon(the color of icon will change) the switch is in OFF state and when we click on Switch the colored icon will again changed to previous white color.

and My code is given below:

**.component.html**

```
 <label class="rating-switch" id="toggleSwitch">
      <input class="rating-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked >
      <div class="slide round" >

      </div>
    </label>    <span class="no-rating-switch" >No Rating</span>

<div class="container">
        <span class="iconss"></span><i (click)="selectedIcon = icon.id" class="stl" [ngClass]="icon.class"
  [style.color]="selectedIcon === icon.id ? '#FF0000' : '#ffffff'" *ngFor="let icon of iconsArray"></i>
</div>
```

**.component.ts**

```
 iconsArray = [
    { id: 1, class: "icon-onlife-smiley-face-1" },
    { id: 2, class: "icon-onlife-smiley-face-2" },
    { id: 3, class: "icon-onlife-smiley-face-3" },
    { id: 4, class: "icon-onlife-smiley-face-4" },
    { id: 5, class: "icon-onlife-smiley-face-5" },
    { id: 6, class: "icon-onlife-smiley-face-6" }
]
selectedIcon = 0;
```

**.component.css**

```
.rating-switch{
  position: relative;
  width: 48px;
  height: 17px;
  margin-top: 3em;

}
.switch, .rating-checkbox { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slide:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  left: 1.2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  top:0.5px;
  background-color: #2b547e;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.rating-checkbox:checked + .slide {
  background-color: #87d3f8;
}

.rating-checkbox:focus + .slide {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #87d3f8;
}

.rating-checkbox:checked + .slide:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(29px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(29px);
  transform: translateX(29px);
}
.slide.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}.slide.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

So my requirement is when we click on any of the icon the switch should be OFF(unchecked)when we click on switch the colored icon will changed white color .

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="rating-switch" id="toggleSwitch">
    <input class="rating-checkbox" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rating">
    <div class="slide round">

    </div>
</label> <span class="no-rating-switch">No Rating</span>

<div class="container">
    <span class="iconss"></span>
    <i (click)="selectedIcon = icon.id" class="stl" [ngClass]="icon.class"
        [style.color]="(selectedIcon === icon.id && !rating) ? '#FF0000' : '#ffffff'"
        *ngFor="let icon of iconsArray"></i>
</div>
```

in ts file

```
rating = true;
iconsArray = [
    { id: 1, class: "icon-onlife-smiley-face-1" },
    { id: 2, class: "icon-onlife-smiley-face-2" },
    { id: 3, class: "icon-onlife-smiley-face-3" },
    { id: 4, class: "icon-onlife-smiley-face-4" },
    { id: 5, class: "icon-onlife-smiley-face-5" },
    { id: 6, class: "icon-onlife-smiley-face-6" }
]
selectedIcon = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks @zainhassan, I think we have to add ts file for rating mentioned in html file,bcz it is not working could you please edit the above code?

Comment: the icons are not clickable and not changing the color

Comment: toggle switch and see if it works

Comment: Yes Toggled but not working